# Webpack with multipage,How to output every page into a single file

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-4

This is my src:

```
src/
   page1
      index.html
      app.js
   page2
      index.html
      app.js
   somecommon
```

The page1 is a pc website,and the page2 is a mobile website, but they have many of the same parts,like same api resuest  or other logic.And I want to output the file  like this

```
build
   page1
     index.html page1.css page1.js
   page2
     index.html page2.css page2.js
   common
     vendors,common
```

Answer (score 0):

You can configure webpack with multiple entry points

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    pageOne: './src/pageOne/index.js',
    pageTwo: './src/pageTwo/index.js',
    pageThree: './src/pageThree/index.js'
  }
};
```

Force web pack to have multiple output paths

```
module.exports = {
    entry: {
      foo: 'foo.js',
      bar: 'bar.js'
    },

    output: {
      path: path.join(__dirname, 'components'),
      filename: '[name]/dist/[name].bundle.js', // Hacky way to force webpack   to have multiple output folders vs multiple files per one path
    }
};
```

Comment: but the output files is not I  describe